# How to restore gradle and java files in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I wanted to look at my gradle and java files as a txt file but I accidentally set the files to open in notepad by default. Now none of my android studio projects will load  because it's trying to load the java and gradle files in notepad and they aren't loading in android studio. Is there anyway to change this back?

Answer (score 0):

Are you now using Android Studio? Please do following steps on your Android Studio

1. Go to Your project Directory and remove .gradle file
2. Import Your project using Android Studio
3. File > Re-Import Gradle Project

Comment: There is no Re-Import Gradle Project option